# How to get a single output from a function with multiple outputs?

Tags: python, function, return

I have the following simple function:

```
def divide(x, y):
    quotient = x/y
    remainder = x % y
    return quotient, remainder  

x = divide(22, 7)
```

If I accesss the variable `x` I get:

```
x
Out[139]: (3, 1)
```

Is there a way to get only the quotient *or* the remainder?

Comment: `x, _ = divide(22, 7)`? You will always get both back, but you can explicitly ignore one or the other, and I would generally recommend this over an additional parameter to set what gets returned.

Comment: or `_, x = divide(22, 7)` if you just want the remainder.  But if all you want is one of them, why call the function at all?  Why not just use `rem = 22 % 7` which is easier to read and to write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two broad options, either:

1. Modify the function to return either or both as appropriate, for example:

   ```
   def divide(x, y, output=(True, True)):
       quot, rem = x // y, x % y
       if all(output):
           return quot, rem
       elif output[0]:
           return quot
       return rem

   quot = divide(x, y, (True, False))
   ```
2. Leave the function as it is, but explicitly ignore one or the other of the returned values:

   ```
   quot, _ = divide(x, y)  # assign one to _, which means ignore by convention
   rem = divide(x, y)[1]  # select one by index
   ```

I would strongly recommend one of the latter formulations; it's *much* simpler!

Comment: A class could also be created to compute and cache the results, which I would strongly recommend over the method-with-output-arg if you really need to get complicated. The options are endless. That said, maybe it would be better to put the simple solution at the beginning?

Comment: @jpmc26 or just a `namedtuple`

Answer (score 5):

You are essentially returning a tuple, which is an iterable we can index, so in the example above:

`print x[0]` would return the quotient and

`print x[1]` would return the remainder

Answer (score 2):

You can either unpack the return values when you call your method:

```
x, y = divide(22, 7)
```

Or you can just grab the first returned value:

```
x = divide(22, 7)[0]
```